# Insert value to column from diffrent textbox vba

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I have a list of machines that had 20 Machines part on them, And I want to be able to insert the list sorted, but when I want to insert 10 different part machines names, it just does not work (it just leave blank cell rather than a value), also is there a possible way to make this code simpler, maybe using for loop.

Any help would be very appreciated

```
    Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daftar Bagian Mesin")

    LastRow = dest.Cells(dest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

   '----------- Part Machine Names -----------'
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox6.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox9.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox12.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox15.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox18.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox21.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox24.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox27.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox30.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox33.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox36.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox39.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox42.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox45.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox48.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox51.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox54.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox57.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox60.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = TextBox63.Value
   '-----------------------------------------'
    
   '----------- Part Machine Code -----------'
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox7.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox10.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox13.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox16.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox19.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox22.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox25.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox28.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox31.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox34.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox37.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox40.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox43.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox46.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox49.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox52.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox55.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox58.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox61.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = TextBox64.Value
   '-----------------------------------------'
   
   '-------- Notes On Part Machines --------'
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox8.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox11.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox14.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox17.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox20.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox23.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox26.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox29.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox32.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox35.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox38.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox41.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox44.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox47.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox50.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox53.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox56.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox59.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox62.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = TextBox65.Value
   '----------------------------------------'
```

Comment: Note that if you write 20 times to the same cell `Cells(LastRow, 1).Value` it is like only writing the last one because all the others get overwritten. It is not clear to me what you are actually trying to do here. Can you please explain what *"does not work"* actually means?

Comment: Well, i want to make 20 values in one column

Value1 (from textbox1)
Value2 (from textbox2)
Value3 (from textbox3)
Value4 (from textbox4)

Comment: Ok but in 20 rows? Or in one cell? or what do you mean? Note that `Cells(LastRow, 1).Value` is always the exact same cell.

Comment: 20 value, in different cell but, in one row, I mistype it should be in one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to rename your text boxes in the userform as follows

```
   '----------- Part Machine Names -----------'
TextBox6    ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames1 
TextBox9    ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames2 
TextBox12   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames3 
TextBox15   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames4 
TextBox18   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames5 
TextBox21   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames6 
TextBox24   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames7 
TextBox27   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames8 
TextBox30   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames9 
TextBox33   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames10 
TextBox36   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames11 
TextBox39   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames12 
TextBox42   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames13 
TextBox45   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames14 
TextBox48   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames15 
TextBox51   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames16 
TextBox54   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames17 
TextBox57   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames18 
TextBox60   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames19 
TextBox63   ' rename to  txtPartMachineNames20 
   '-----------------------------------------'
```

The text boxes for `Part Machine Code`

```
TextBox7    ' rename to  txtPartMachineCode1 
TextBox10   ' rename to  txtPartMachineCode2

' and so on (you get the idea).
```

Then you can use one loop for all three types of textboxes (`Part Machine Names`, `Part Machine Code` and `Notes On Part Machines`):

```
Dim dest As Worksheet
Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daftar Bagian Mesin")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = dest.Cells(dest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 20
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(RowOffset:=i-1).Value = Controls("txtPartMachineNames" & i).Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Offset(RowOffset:=i-1).Value = Controls("txtPartMachineCode" & i).Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Offset(RowOffset:=i-1).Value = Controls("txtNotesOnPartMachine" & i).Value
next i
```